# How to recode numerical variable into categorical?

Tags: r, recode

Hi I've been trying to recode numerical variables into categorical.

For example, using `mtcars`, I am trying to divide `mpg` into 2 category < 25 & =>25

These are the codes that I've tried, but getting error message.

```
data=mtcars
summary(mtcars$mpg)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
10.40   15.43   19.20   20.09   22.80   33.90 

mpgcat <- cut(mpg, breaks = (0,24.99,34), labels = c("0","1"))
```

> Error: unexpected ',' in "mpgcat <- cut(mpg, breaks = (0,"

Comment: Improved formatting and added relevant tag for R. So you'll get attention by other users here.

Comment: When you have `breaks = (0, 24.99,34)` you need `breaks = c(0,24.99,34)`. Voting to closse as typo.

Comment: Voting to close per Gregor's comment as well, however, posting the full, working line for clarity: `cut(mtcars$mpg, breaks = c(0,24.99,34), labels = c("0","1"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` divides the range of `x` into intervals and codes the values in x according to which interval they fall. The leftmost interval corresponds to level one, the next leftmost to level two and so on.

**breaks** is either a numeric vector of two or more unique cut points or a single number (greater than or equal to 2) giving the number of intervals into which `x` is to be cut.

So you'll need some script code e.g.:

```
data=mtcars
summary(mtcars$mpg)
mpgcut <- cut(mtcars$mpg, breaks = c(0,24.99,34), labels = c("0","1"))
mpgcut
```

to get a result like this:

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1
```